# What does "vt", "vpr" and "vi" mean when referring to verbs in a Spanish dictionary?

Tags: gramática, recursos

Does anybody comprehend these abbreviations in the image, used in Oxford's Essential Spanish Dictionary?

[image]

It says:

> **venga|nza** *f* revenge. **~r** ***vt*** avenge. **~rse** ***vpr*** take revenge (**de**, **por** for) (**en** on). **~tivo** adj vindictive.
>
> **veni|da** *f* arrival; (*vuelta*) return **~dero** *adj* coming. **~r** ***vi*** come.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is telling you that:

- *vengar* is a transitive verb (**vt** - *verbo transitivo*) which takes an object, to avenge someone.
- *vengarse* is a pronominal verb (**vpr** - *verbo pronominal*) form which always has the pronoun attached and which has it declined to agree with the subject. In this case it means to take revenge either for (*de, por*) or on (*en*).
  Pronominal verbs are explained in this Wikipedia article https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbo_pronominal (in Spanish) and are usually referred to by English speakers as reflexive verbs although the truth is more complex in general.
- *venir* is an intransitive verb (**vi** - *verbo intransitivo*) which does not take an object. You just come, you do not come something.

Comment: As a native Spanish speaker I am trying to think of examples with prepositions ("vengarse por/en...") and it seems to me that "vengar" is a particularly difficult example. "Vestirse" is arguably the standard vpr.